# Infinite axioms/Group of axioms

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, axioms

When we talk about an axiom, shouldn't it be a group of axioms since we have an axiom for each variable?.

For example, "B ⇒ (C ⇒B)" is an axiom schema standing for an infinite number of axioms (Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Mendelson). Therefore, x1 * 0=0 should be an axiom schema too, since it stands for an infinite number of variables and therefore we have an infinite number of axioms. Am I wrong?

Comment: Variable?  Of what? Can you please expand your post and give an example of what you mean?

Comment: What its a "variable" in this context?

Comment: When an axiom is a group of axioms what is an axiom?

Comment: For example, "B ⇒ (C ⇒B)" is an axiom schema standing for an infinite number of axioms (Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Mendelson). Therefore, x1 * 0=0 should be an axiom schema too, since it stands for an infinite number of variables and therefore we have an infinite number of axioms. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Jose What’s wrong with the idea that an axiom is a rule, which gives rise to many different cases? It’s still one “rule”, even if there might be infinitely many cases in which it can “apply”. Note that I’m trying to understand how you’re thinking, hence this usage of vague language (“cases”, etc.)

Comment: @Jose could be… depends on the situation. Often all the versions with different variables will be provable from one another so only one version is needed.

Comment: Sometimes authors have axioms and a rule of uniform substitution instead of axiom schema.  In which case, I don't see why we would talk about a set of axioms.

Answer (score 1):

$x * 0 = 0$ is really shorthand for the claim $\forall x \ x * 0 = 0$. So this is really just one specific first-order logic claim, and therefore one specific axiom, not an axiom schema like $B \to (A \to B)$.

You will often see Greek letters being used as statement/formula variables used in mathematically laying out axioms. So since different FOL formulas can be filled in for those variable we are really dealing with an axiom schema. So you'll often see something like $\varphi \to (\psi\to \varphi)$, and now you immediately know you're dealing with  an axiom schema.

But note that we don't have anything like $\varphi * 0 = 0$. Instead we have $x * 0 = 0$, and $x$ here is not a statement/formula variable, but an object variable as part of the very language of FOL. Sure, it has many instances when applying the universal elimination rule, but that is not what makes it a schema. It is still one specific expression in the language of FOL.

Indeed, all of the first 6 axioms of Peabno Arithmetic (I am guessing that is what you are looking at) are specific FOL statements, and therefore specific axioms, not axiom schemas.  The induction axiom, however, is an axiom schema :

$(\varphi(0) \land \forall x (\varphi(x) \to \varphi(s(x)))) \to \forall x \ \varphi(x)$

Here, the $\varphi(x)$ is any formula that has $x$ as a free variable, and so this axiom schema has an infinite number of instances which are genuine FOL statements.

Of course, if we are doing second-order logic, we can write:

$\forall \varphi ((\varphi(0) \land \forall x (\varphi(x) \to \varphi(s(x)))) \to \forall x \ \varphi(x))$

and *that* is one specific SOL axiom, and therefore not an axiom schema for SOL.